# Trying to understand updateCursor() for python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2. I am attempting to write a script that will cycle through the classes in a database and change the attribution of 1 row.

Is my variable "lyr" being recognized as the classes in the dataset?

When referencing an attribute to change, do you reference the alias or the actual name of the attribute?

Code sample:

```
import arcpy

dataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.worspace = dataset
classList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()


for lyr in classList:
     rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(lyr)
     for row in rows:
         othField = row.getValue("OTH")
         if othField == "No Information":
             row.OTH = "noInformation"
             rows.updateRow(row)
         else:
             pass
del row
del rows
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? You should use the newer `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/018w/018w00000014000000.htm

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was informed of this by a coworker as well. I would never have figured this out had it not been for you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You reference the actual field name rather than an alias.

When debugging a script, I always hard code the paths to directories--once that is working, then add the `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)`. Also, it is preferrable to wrap a cursor in a `with` statement ([documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000)). Finally, the `pass` statement is extraneous. Try the following:

```
import arcpy

dataset = r'C:\path\to\dataset'
arcpy.env.workspace = dataset
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcs:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "OTH") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == "No Information":
                row[0] = "noInformation"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: There's a typo when setting the workspace: you're missing a 'k' (arcpy.env.workspace).

Comment: @SIslam - it's not my question.